# Find records from MySQL which is updated within last hour but not created within last hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query from MySQL where posts will come only which is updated within last hour but not created in last hour.

Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM posts
   WHERE (updated_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))) AS A

WHERE (created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
```

But this query doesn't give me right result.

I am attaching sample posts in CSV and adding result output from this query.

Sample: [[image: Sample Posts]]

Query Output: [[image: Query Results]]

Comment: Your sample data does not help explain anything.  Please include the data directly in your question.  Do **not** include external links.

Comment: Who downvote this ? Can you please explain why you downvote ?

Comment: I have countered your downvote, but it probably happen because the reader of your question took it to be a "why isn't this code working" question, since it's not really reproducible.

Comment: I have added images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need both conditions in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE
    updated_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND
    created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: I have tried this but when I add both conditions results showing records which is created 1 hour before and updated 1 hours before.

Comment: Then add some sample data to your question which shows that my query has a problem.  I don't see anything wrong with my logic.

Comment: I have added sample and query output, please check.

Comment: This solution works. Need to convert date with UTC. Thansk Tim